# What does "background" FN and FP in the confusion matrix of YOLOv7 stand for

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, object-detection, yolo, confusion-matrix

I ran a yolov7 model to detect trash and I want to know how to interpret the confusion matrix. Image consists of two classes: either the object that is detected is trash or not trash. But there seems to be a new class called Background FN along the row and Background FP along the column.

I understand that FN and FP mean false positive and false negative. But I assumed that for a 2 class problem there's gonna be two rows and two columns with the typical TP, TN, FP, FN values. Now there's these extra probability values and I don't understand where they come from.
The dataset I used comes from here: https://universe.roboflow.com/nam-nhat/trash-dvdrr?utm_source=augmented-startups&utm_medium=video&utm_campaign=yolov7-tutorial
This confusion matrix is created automatically with other curves like precision vs confidence curve and precision vs recall curves once the yolov7 model is built. Now I want to predict the accuracy of the model as well as the false alarm rate, so I thought knowing the TP, TN, FP, FN values will be helpful but I don't understand this background class.
I'm unable to post image of confusion matrix so I'm making a table of it.

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Not Trash</th>
<th>Trash</th>
<th>Background FP</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Not Trash</td>
<td>0.77</td>
<td>0.02</td>
<td>0.27</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Trash</td>
<td>0.02</td>
<td>0.97</td>
<td>0.73</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Background FN</td>
<td>0.21</td>
<td>0.02</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Object detection is a bit different; understand it as follows.

**Background FP** refers to background objects that do not belong to either of the classes but detected as one of them.

**Background FN** refers to Trash or Non-trash objects missed by the detector and considered as some other background objects.

Answer (score 0):

These additional classes represent false negative and false positive predictions for **background elements**.

"Background FP" and "Background FN" are additional classes that are specific to the YOLOv7 model and the **task of detecting trash**.

**Background FN :** refers to the number of false negatives where the model failed to detect an object in regions where no object is present (i.e., missed detections of the "background" class).

**Background FP :** refers to the number of false positives where the model incorrectly detected an object in regions where no object is present (i.e., incorrect detections of the "background" class).